# How to create a directory using environment property in Java?

Tags: java

I want to create a directory in my local machine like: Desktop/images/ads/(date).

```
 String uploadDir = env.getProperty("static.path")  + "ads/" + LocalDate.now();
        File file = new File(uploadDir);
        if (!file.exists()) {
            file.mkdir();
        }
```

But above code gives me a No such file or directory error.How to solve it?

Comment: Do you need `ads` need to be created too? If so, you should use `mkdirs`, with an extra `s`.

Comment: Please add the stack trace of your error to your question.

Answer (score 1):

Use the newer Java 7 NIO.2 API, i.e. [`Path`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Path.html), [`Paths`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Paths.html) and [`Files`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html):

```java
Path uploadDir = Paths.get(env.getProperty("static.path"), "ads", LocalDate.now().toString());
Files.createDirectories(uploadDir);
```